# PHP - insert Unicode data into MYSQL formatted properly

Tags: php, mysql, json, unicode

I am inserting some data from a s`json` file into `mysql` database. Some of the data is formatted using `unicode`.

When I `echo` the data on the browser is showing fine however, it is inserted in the database not formatted properly.

In the database I am using as Collation `utf8_unicode_ci`.

JSON data:
`anch\u2019io`, `sar\u00e0`

Showing in the Browser:
`anch'io`, `sarà`

Showing in the mysql database:
`anchâ€™io`, `sarÃ`

How can I inserted in the database the text properly formatted?

PHP

```
$getUrl = "https://example.com/79809000.json";
$json_level = file_get_contents($getUrl);
$data_level = json_decode($json_level);

$text = $data_level->{"text"};

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `70_level`(`text`) VALUES ('$text')");
```

I have tried to use `addslashes`, `htmlentities` but it does not work.

Comment: "Showing in the mysql database" - how exactly you look at the data?

Comment: You should make sure to use the correct connection collate both in your PHP code and in the application you use to view the data

Comment: I am looking with phpMyAdmin

Comment: Try to add `mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");` right after you did the connection.

Comment: (Note the this will only affect the new data you will insert, but it will also affect the data you select, so if you also show unicode data - you might need to re-insert it to the database).

Comment: @Dekel It worked.. Thank you so much !!

Comment: you are welcome :) care to vote the answer as well?

Comment: See "Mojibake" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not using `utf8` as your character set connection/collation connection.

The easiest way to fix this will be to use

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(...);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

The `SET NAMES` query should be the first query you run, so make sure you put it right after your `mysqli_connect` function.

> Note that this change will affect all the data, so if you already have data in the database - you will need to re-insert it using the new (utf8) charset.